# How to add Meteor framework/platform support to existing module in Intellij IDEA (14.1.5)?

Tags: meteor, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I need to add Meteor framework to existing module.
As I can see this option is available for new modules (static web->Meteor app).
But I can't find how to make this with existing module.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Meteor is a full-stack framework - it doesn't really make sense to "add" it to a project.

Comment: For example, I want to be able to open a template helper code from a template by ctrl+b hotkey combination.

Answer (score 0):

You just ope the project containing .meteor folder and make sure the meteor plugin is active.

[image: Project structure]

Answer (score 0):

Settings->Languages & Frameworks->Javascript->Templates

Tick "Open HTML files as Handlebars/Mustache" option.